# Is there any function that compares distributions of two populations?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Imagine I have two populations that I want to test whether they exhibit similar shape distributions. Is there such a function that does this sort of testing already implemented?

I am asking this since one of the assumptions of the Mann-Whitney U test is that both populations to compare exhibit similar shapes. I could compare whether they exhibited similar variance, but this is not what this assumption requires.

For instance, if I have

```
data1=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 10^3];
data2=RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[1, 2], 10^3];
```

This function would test whether `data1` and `data2` exhibit similar shapes. Sorry if this is a very small question.

Edit0: I had posted the following 2 edits *before* seeing there were two answers that already tackle the main issue here. These two edits are side questions for this thread and should probably be asked elsewhere. Sorry for that.

Edit1: The assumptions indicated in the documentation for `MannWhitneyTest[]` indicates `MannWhitneyTest assumes that the data is elliptically symmetric about a common spatial median in the multivariate case.`. I wonder if the assumption about the shape of the two populations is not required in this case?

Edit2: Is it possible that `LocationTest[{data1,data2},Automatic, "MannWhitney"]` could bypass the issue of sample shape?

The reason why I'm asking these two questions is that the number of tests I'm performing is very large.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ask on stats.SE or math.SE?  Once you have a theoretical answer, you could ask how to implement it in *M*, if you need to.  In any caes, I think the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov\[Dash]Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test) is for this sort of thing, although it's outside my comfort zone.

Comment: I would have expected that something like `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[
data1, EmpiricalDistribution[data2] ]` would work, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: Indeed, I had read about the `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[]` (and was about to post them here), but it should only work on normally distributed samples.

Comment: Nope. From documentation: "*KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data,**dist**] 
tests whether data is distributed according to **dist** using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.*"

Comment: @rhermans you are right, I am confusing other information I've read. Either way it doesn't solve my problem :\

Comment: `QuantilePlot[data1,data2]` would give you a visual idea (Q-Q plot). straight line for equally distributed sets.

Comment: On a side note (which probably helps me answering my main issue, though it doesn't answer the main question): I was thinking about testing the two samples using `VarianceTest[]` so that the `MannWhitneyTest[]` would effectively be a comparison of medians.

Comment: eh... I just posted two edits and now I notice I have two nice answers :) thanks guys!

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its likely that better approaches may come later improving over a previous reply and experienced users may point to caveats. Therefore, new users may **wait 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Comment: Thanks, I usually do accept most *meaningful* answers that I get in 24-72 hours, as you can see for most of my threads (>80% of them should have accepted answers; the ones that don't are because the potential answers do not entirely address the issue at hand).
...I hope the problem wasn't related with my upvotes, as I really think both answers introduced useful information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Data

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 10^3];
data2 = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[1, 2], 10^3];
```

### Visual comparison

[`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) and [`KolmogorovSmirnovTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KolmogorovSmirnovTest.html) seem to work. But first check visually.

```
QuantilePlot[data1, data2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly not equally distributed.

For contrast

```
data3 = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[1, 2], 10^4];

QuantilePlot[data3, data2]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Equally distributed

### Tests

```
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data1, data2]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

```
KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data3, data2]
```

> ```
> 0.17038
> ```

```
DistributionFitTest[data3, data2, "ShortTestConclusion"]
```

> "Do not reject"

```
DistributionFitTest[data1, data2, "ShortTestConclusion"]
```

> "Reject"

That been "**Reject**" the hypothesis that the two distributions are equal.

Comment: I was just now looking into the `KolmogorovSmirnovTest` too! But shouldn't it be `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data1, EmpiricalDistribution[data2]]`?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`KolmogorovSmirnovTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KolmogorovSmirnovTest.html)  basic examples under "*Compare the distributions of two datasets:*"

Comment: sorry! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

```
SeedRandom[1];

data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 3], 10^3];
data2 = RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[1, 2], 10^3];
```

Use [`ProbabilityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityPlot.html) for a visual comparison.

```
ProbabilityPlot[
 Evaluate[Tooltip /@ {data1, data2}],
 PlotLegends -> {"data1", "data2"}]
```

[image]

This indicates that `data1` is normal but that `data2` is not.

```
ProbabilityPlot[data1, data2]
```

[image]

This indicates that the distributions are not similar. Similar distributions are close to the diagonal.

Use [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) to test if data is normally distributed (default) or any other specified distribution.

```
DistributionFitTest[
    #, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"][
   "TestDataTable", All] & /@ {data1, data2}
```

[image]